# %название_проекта%.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова

Tags: c, односвязный-список

Код является попыткой реализации односвязного списка. Выводит ошибку "проект вызвал срабатывание точки останова." в строке

```
free(head);
```

функции slist_delete.

```
 // Forward declaration
typedef struct slist_entry *pslist_entry;
typedef struct slist *pslist;

struct slist_entry
{
    pslist_entry next;
    int value;
};

struct slist
{
    int list_size; // sugar
    pslist_entry head;
};

/*
 * Creates an empty list
 * Params: none
 * Returns pointer to the list
 */
pslist slist_new(void);

/*
 * Deletes list and all the elements
 * Params: list - pointer to the list
 * Returns none
 */
void slist_delete(pslist list);

/*
 * Insert element in the beginning of the list
 * Params: list - pointer to the list, element - int value
 * Returns if the insertion is correct or not
 */
int slist_insert(pslist list, int value);

/*
 * Remove from the list all the element with given value
 * Params: list - pointer to the list, element - int value
 * Returns if the removing is correct or not
 */
int slist_remove(pslist list, int value);

/*
 * Print values of the element in the list
 * Params: list - pointer to the list
 * Returns none
 */
void slist_print(pslist list);
/* Create new empty list */
pslist slist_new(void)
{
    pslist list = malloc(sizeof(struct slist));
    if (NULL == list)
    {
        printf("ERROR: failed allocation of memory for new list!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    list->list_size = 0;
    list->head = NULL;

    return list;
}

/* Removes head from the list and returns it*/
pslist_entry slist_pop(pslist list)
{
    list->head = list->head->next;
    return list->head;
}

/* For each element free memory */
void slist_delete(pslist list)
{
    pslist_entry head = list->head;
    while (NULL != head) 
    {
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free(head);
    }
    free(list);
}

/* Allocate the element
   Put at the end */
int slist_insert(pslist list, int value)
{
    struct slist_entry *pnew = malloc(sizeof(struct slist_entry));
    if (NULL == pnew)
    {
        printf("ERROR: failed allocation of memory for new element!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    pnew->next = list->head;
    pnew->value = value;
    printf("New element: %d\n", pnew->value);
    list->head = pnew;
    list->list_size++;
    return 0;
}

/* Go through the list, remove if value is equal */
int slist_remove(pslist list, int value)
{
    pslist_entry current = list->head;
    pslist_entry prev = list->head;
    if (NULL == current)
    {
        printf("ERROR: removing element from empty list!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        if (current->value == value)
        {
            while (!(prev->next == current))
            {
                prev = prev->next;
            }
            prev->next = current->next;
            return current->value;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}


/* For each element print in value */
void slist_print(pslist list)
{ 
    pslist_entry current = list->head;
    if (NULL == current)
    {
        printf("Sorry...the list is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (NULL != current->next)
        {
            printf("%d -> ", current->value);
            current = current->next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", current->value);
    }

}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем связана ошибка и как ее можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

- ```
  void slist_delete(pslist list)
  {
      pslist_entry head = list->head;
      while (NULL != head) 
      {
          list->head = list->head->next;
          free(head);
      }
      free(list);
  }
  ```

  В этом цикле значение переменной `head` никогда не меняется/не обновляется. То есть в заголовке цикла вы все время проверяете одно и то же `head` и в цикле вы применяете `free` к одному и тому же `head`. Поведение не определено.
- Функция `int slist_remove(pslist list, int value)` не умеет правильно удалять самый первый элемент списка.

  Также, поиск делается до

  ```
  while (current->next != NULL)
  ```

  А что, самый последний элемент проверять не нужно?

  Также, вы везде упорно используете yoda-условия, а здесь внезапно `current->next != NULL`...

  Также, поиск `prev` сделан неэффективно. Такое впечатление, что автор начинал с пониманием того, как нужно делать правильно, но потом "скатился".

  Также `while (!(prev->next == current))`? Серьезно? По остальному коду видно, что вы уже вроде знакомы с оператором `!=`.
- В `int slist_insert(pslist list, int value)` поддерживается `list_size`. А куда пропала поддержка `list_size` из остальных функций?

  Также, вы наопределяли typedef-имен для указательных типов (дурная практика) и везде ими усердно пользуетесь. Но здесь вдруг `struct slist_entry *pnew`...